# How to read from a pipe using read()

Tags: c++, linux, file, signals, exec

I need to write a program that, using the ancestor, writes to the channel from the input file and then the descendant processes read from the pipe in turn and synchronize using signals, however, when the child process starts, I get errno = 9 (bad file descriptor) while reading from the channel, what could be the problem? Father's code you can see below, and children's codes you can see below. Father code(main.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <wait.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    sigset_t new_mask;
    sigemptyset(&new_mask);
    sigaddset(&new_mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&new_mask, SIGUSR2);
    sigaddset(&new_mask, SIGQUIT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &new_mask, NULL);
    int fildes[2];
    pid_t pid1;
    pid_t pid2;
    int last_sig;
    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        execl("1","1", "output1.txt", &fildes[0], &fildes[1],NULL);
        close(fildes[0]);
        _exit(0);
    }
    else {
        pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0) {
            execl("2","2", "output2.txt", &fildes[0], &fildes[1], NULL);
            close(fildes[0]);
            _exit(0);
        }
        else {
            close(fildes[0]);
            cout<<"Parent"<<endl;
            ifstream file("input.txt");
            if (file.is_open()) {
                string str;
                while(getline(file, str)){
                    write(fildes[1], &str[0], strlen(str.c_str()));
                    cout<<"PARENT пишет:" << str << endl;
                }
                close(fildes[1]);
                killpg(0, SIGQUIT);
                file.close();
            }
            int st1, st2;
            waitpid(pid1, &st1, 0);
            waitpid(pid2, &st2, 0);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

First child(1.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <cerrno>  

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    close(*argv[3]);
    sigset_t mask_sig;
    sigemptyset(&mask_sig);
    sigaddset(&mask_sig, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&mask_sig, SIGQUIT);
    ofstream file;
    int last_sig;
    char ch;
    file.open(argv[1], ios::app);
    sigwait(&mask_sig, &last_sig);
    file << read(*argv[2], &ch, 1)  << endl;
    file << errno << endl;
    while(read(*argv[2], &ch, 1) > 0){
        file << "z" << endl;
        file << ch;
        killpg(0, SIGUSR2);
        sigwait(&mask_sig, &last_sig);
    }
    killpg(0, SIGUSR2);
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Second child(2.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <wait.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    close(*argv[3]);
    sigset_t mask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGQUIT);
    sigset_t mask_sig;
    sigemptyset(&mask_sig);
    sigaddset(&mask_sig, SIGUSR2);
    ofstream file;
    int last_sig;
    char ch;
    file.open(argv[1], ios::app);
    sigwait(&mask, &last_sig);
    sigwait(&mask_sig, &last_sig);
    while(read(*argv[2], &ch, 1) > 0){
        file << ch;
        killpg(0, SIGUSR1);
        sigwait(&mask_sig, &last_sig);
    }
    killpg(0, SIGUSR1);
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `execl("1","1", "output1.txt", &fildes[0], &fildes[1],NULL);` Your design has fundamental problems. You are trying to pass pointer/address values from one process to another. That won't work. Virtual memory addresses are only valid within the process. It can't be passed around like that.

Comment: @kaylum but it worked in other program, but there child's process was writting and father's process was reading

Comment: Sorry, don't believe it. Forget the other program. Just think from first principles. The fundamental principle is that each process has it's own address space. An address X in process A will not refer to the same thing as address X in process B. This is part of process seperation and is one of the key responsibilities of the Operating System.

Comment: Note that after a `fork` the child process gets the same open file descriptors as the parent process. Perhaps that's what you did in the other program. But that's not the same as trying to pass addresses as arguments to a process.